# I have a 2002 Mitsubishi eclipse 2.4 sohc 16 valve 4g64, timing belt teeth separated

Tags: engine

I took the head off, expecting the worst, but the piston heads don't have a scratch on them, and the valves aren't bent, just a lot of carbon. What is to be expected; should I rebuild this engine or scrap it and get another?

Comment: If you serviced it like you serviced the belt then get another engine.

Comment: What let you to pull the head?  Usually a compression and/or leak-down test is done to confirm that there has been some damage.  A borescope is also useful.  At this point what damage have you found?